# I want to change 3d model in vuforia Augmented Reality in android

Tags: android, vuforia

I had downloaded android vuforia sdk from https://developer.vuforia.com.

I want to change teapot object to custom object.

I read so many tutorial but there is no such tutorial to change 3d object.

https://developer.vuforia.com/resources/dev-guide/replacing-teapot
also reading this blog but i don't understand.

Please help me.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can check following source code.

https://github.com/sidneibjunior/vuforia-jpct

Use jPCT java 3d game engine.

Comment: Can we place the .3ds object inside this engine? If you have any idea please reply.Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

rajawali is more better to work for 3d game engine with vuforia, i tried many : min3d,jpct-ae, rajawali etc and find rajawali to perform best.
integration complete sample: https://github.com/MasDennis/RajawaliVuforia